# Module not found after i install react mdl

Tags: reactjs

I installed react mdl after creating my react app. I added  in my html and I then added a navigation layout in App.js with importing import { Layout, Header, Navigation, Drawer, Content } from 'react-mdl';
Added import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js'; in index.js
node version: v10.15.0

I get this error: 
./node_modules/react-mdl/lib/Switch.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\randomp\code\englishsoundfront\node_modules\react-mdl\lib'

Comment: Try removing node_modules and package-lock.json and `npm install` again.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still the same issue! I also tried to install switch.js manually but I can't figure out how to do that!